# When should we use ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#

I stumbled over ListCollectionView and made me think about the best practices. When and why should i use ListCollectionView over ObservableCollection? for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When and why should i use ListCollectionView over ObservableCollection?

Probably never...

`ListCollectionView` represents a view of a collection; it is created when you use `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` on a collection that implements `IList`. You typically don't create it yourself.